# How to assert the page title using AngularJS Scenario

Tags: angularjs, angular-scenario

I tried the following but got an error : expect undefined toBe "/"

```
    browser().navigateTo('/');
    expect(browser().location().url()).toBe("/");
    expect(document.title).toBe("something");
```

Page does have a title "something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the test website runs in a frame, document.title would not work.

However, you can use this:

```
expect(element('title').text()).toBe("something");
```